# Mysql select data from table.. and echo value where id = $id

Tags: mysql

In Mysql php I need to get all data from database by using

```
 select * from table_name
```

and

```
echo value in page where id = 1
```

I have a table with 5 columns and 6 rows I need to echo value as per column id

For exm. table

```
id  -- name -- age -- dob -- remarks
1  -- rajju  -- 20 -- 24/12/2015  -- good
2  -- prasad  -- 15  -- 12/2/2010 -- bad
3  -- kranti  -- 22  -- 05/05/2000 -- average
```

Now I need to select all db and

```
echo value like <`echo $name where id=1` > your health is <`echo $remarks where id=1`> better then <`echo $name where id=2`>
```

my end value would be like this

```
Dear Raju your health is good better then prasad
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
 select * from table_name where id = 1
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: but i aleady selected db into array now i need to echo value like name where id = 1

Answer (score 0):

do you need to compare only with 1 user?
if so then you can do like this

```
$mainid = 1; //(you can get this value dynamically)
$compareid=2; //(you can get this value dynamically)
$result1=(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$mainid);
$result2=(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$compareid);
```

Now you can use value

```
<?php echo Hello $result1->name your health seems better than $result2->name.
```